# Induced mapping on homotopy classes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> Let $f: Y_1 \rightarrow Y_2$ -- arbitrary continuos mapping. Define
>   induced mapping $f_*: \pi (X, Y_1) \rightarrow \pi (X, Y_2)$.

Attempt: I think, this mapping should work: $f_*([g]) := [f \circ g]$. But I don't understand how to show correctness. In other words, I need to show that if $[g_1] = [g_2]$, then $[f \circ g_1] = [f \circ g_1].$ Maybe it somehow follows from the definitions, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess at the definition is correct! So as you pointed out, to show correctness, we need to show that if $g_1,g_2$ are path homotopic, then $f\circ g_1$ and $f \circ g_2$ are path homotopic. Can you find such a homotopy given that there exists one between $g_1$ and $g_2$?

Comment: Can we just take $H' : X \times I \rightarrow Y_2, H'(x, t) = f(H(x, t))$? f is continuous so we get a homology, I guess.

Comment: You can indeed - nice one!